# "'^^Command not found" Terminal force quits

Tags: 13.04, command-line

So I was trying to make an android from source when I guess I typed in some weird command that didnt work, next thing I know,  I get the error "^^Command not found" and then my terminal force quits. Now every time I try to open the terminal I get the same message and it force quits. I really need some help here and keep in mind that I cant actually use the terminal to fix this.

Comment: How are you trying to launch the terminal? Do other terminals work? Try running `xterm`.

Comment: Can you use the physical terminal(using Ctrl+Alt+F1)? Use Ctrl+Alt+F7 to exit from that terminal.

Comment: The physical terminal works, but I cant run any terminals from the software center

Answer (score 1):

You likely corrupted your `~/.bashrc`. Make a backup copy of that file if you have personalized settings in it, then copy `/etc/skel/.bashrc` to `~/.bashrc` to overwrite it. Don't forget that the filename starts with a `.`  so it is hidden in nautilus, so press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> in nautilus to show the hidden files.

Or if you know about bash scripting then you just have to correct the problem in `~/.bashrc` with any text editor.

(Or you paste contents of that file here so wee can look into it.)